# Is it possible to set a timer inside a signal handler?

Tags: linux, unix, timer, signals, posix

I need to keep an isochronous *event* synchronized with a timer-oriented signal handler.

Can I use `timer_settime()` inside a signal handler to adjust the next timer expiration, and thus keep my timer-oriented signal handler synchronized with the *event*?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after some other research I found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6440966/6998967) a link to [this part of POSIX specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html) (*IEEE Std 1003.1-2008* or *POSIX.1-2008*).

The specification gives (in [**System Interfaces**->**Pointer to a function** subsection](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_04_03_03)) a list of async-signal-safe functions to use in signal handlers, and *timer_settime()* is part of them.

I appreciate another more technical and detailed answer, although my question was resolved. Thanks!